# Apache Web Server Is Running But httpd Is Not Running

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm facing a weird problem. When I access the web-accessible directory of my server via domain linked to it. It says:-

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

When I run this command on my server (via putty), it displays few processes ids demonstrating that Apache web server is running (correct me).

```
root@...:~# pgrep apache
4733
13505
13506
13507
13508
13686
14199
17672
```

But when I run this command, it says that httpd: unrecognized service

```
root@...:~# service httpd status
httpd: unrecognized service
```

Some other commands output:-

```
root@...:~# ps aux|grep -i http
root     29401  0.0  0.0   6460   792 pts/0    S+   02:21   0:00 grep --color=auto -i http

root@...:~# chkconfig --list | grep httpd
-bash: chkconfig: command not found

root@...:~# find / -name httpd*
/var/www/vhosts/lvps5-35-241-230.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs
/var/www/vhosts/.skel/0/httpdocs
/opt/psa/var/httpd_restart
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/fr/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/pt-br/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/da/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/zh-cn/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/tr/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/en/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ja/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ko/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/de/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/es/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/httpd.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd.pem

root@...:~# whereis httpd
httpd:

root@...:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

root@...:~# ls /etc/init.d
README             hostname           network-interface-container  plymouth-upstart-bridge  rc              spamassassin            udevtrigger
apache2            hwclock            network-interface-security   portmap                  rc.local        ssh                     umountfs
bind9              hwclock-save       networking                   portmap-wait             rcS             stop-bootlogd           umountnfs.sh
bluetooth          keymap.sh          ondemand                     postfix                  reboot          stop-bootlogd-single    umountroot
bootlogd           killprocs          passwd                       procps                   rpcbind-boot    sudo                    unattended-upgrades
console-screen.sh  klogd              pc-remote                    psa                      rsync           sw-cp-server            urandom
courier-imap       module-init-tools  plymouth                     psa-firewall             saslauthd       sysklogd                wide-dhcpv6-client
cron               modules_dep.sh     plymouth-log                 psa-firewall-forward     screen-cleanup  udev                    x11-common
dbus               mongodb            plymouth-ready               psa-spamassassin         sendsigs        udev-fallback-graphics  xinetd
fetchmail          mysql              plymouth-splash              quota                    single          udev-finish
halt               network-interface  plymouth-stop                quotarpc                 skeleton        udevmonitor

root@...:~# ls /etc/xinetd.d
chargen  daytime  discard  echo  ftp_psa  poppassd_psa  time
```

Comment: Are you sure the service is named "httpd"? If I remember correctly the Ubuntu service for apache is called "apache2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the command 'lsof' and look for 'http' you can easily see if your Apache website processes are indeed running on Ubuntu.  In my case:

```
 sudo lsof | grep ':http '
```

And I see

```
 apache2    2202                 root    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
 apache2   22949             www-data    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
 apache2   22950             www-data    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
 apache2   22951             www-data    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
 apache2   22952             www-data    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
 apache2   22953             www-data    4u     IPv6              15516      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Thus confirming that the processes in Unbuntu are indeed named 'apache2' and not httpd.

Comment: How can I confirm that apache2 is running fine and httpd is not required? When I go to the my server's IP address, it says `Not Found`... `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`. Isn't this proves that something is not working in apache2?

Comment: It proves that you might have some problems in the configuration file somewhere but I was under the impression that you were trying to confirm that the processes were present.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://serverfault.com/questions/676310/setup-apache-virtual-host-and-did-everything-necessary-still-not-found-error

Answer (score -1):

What you want is:

```
#systemctl status apache2
```

not ... `httpd`.

Comment: The question is about Ubuntu version 12.04.